# Weighted data problems, mean is fine, but Covar and std look wrong, how do I adjust?

Tags: python, math, numpy, pandas, covariance

I'm trying to apply a weighted filter on data rather the use raw data before calculating stats, mu, std and covar. But the results clearly need adjusting.

```
# generate some data and a filter
f_n = 100.
np.random.seed(seed=101); 
foo = np.random.rand(f_n,3)
foo = DataFrame(foo).add(1).pct_change()
f_filter = np.arange(f_n,.0,-1)
f_filter = 1.0 / (f_filter**(f_filter/f_n))
# nominalise the filter ... This could be where I'm going wrong?
f_filter = f_filter * (f_n / f_filter.sum())
```

Now we are ready to look at some results

```
print foo.mul(f_filter,axis=0).mean()
print foo.mean()

0    0.039147
1    0.039013
2    0.037598
dtype: float64
0    0.035006
1    0.042244
2    0.041956
dtype: float64
```

Means all look in line, but when we look at covar and std they are significantly different in terms of scale and also direction

```
print foo.mul(f_filter,axis=0).cov()
print foo.cov()

          0         1         2
0  0.124766 -0.038954  0.027256
1 -0.038954  0.204269  0.056185
2  0.027256  0.056185  0.203934

      0         1         2
0  0.070063 -0.014926  0.010434
1 -0.014926  0.099249  0.015573
2  0.010434  0.015573  0.087060

print foo.mul(f_filter,axis=0).std()
print foo.std()

0    0.353223
1    0.451961
2    0.451590
dtype: float64
0    0.264694
1    0.315037
2    0.295060
dtype: float64
```

Any ideas why, how can we adjust the filter or to adjust the covar matrix to make it more comparable?

Comment: are you trying to calculate a weighted mean?  It looks like you are weighting the numbers and THEN calculating the mean which won't give you the weighted mean.

Comment: I'm experimenting with is alternative methods of EWMA's that work on a strict window method, I'm more interested in the weighted Std and Cov. just wondered if there was any other approaches as this clearly isn't robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your weighting function. (Do you want Gaussian random numbers or uniform r.v.?) See this plot

```
f_n = 100.
np.random.seed(seed=101); 
# ??? you want uniform random variable? or is this just a typo and you want normal random variable?
foo = np.random.rand(f_n,3)
foo = DataFrame(foo)
f_filter = np.arange(f_n,.0,-1)

# here is the problem, uneven weight makes a artificial trend, causing non-stationary. covariance only works for stationary data.
# =============================================
f_filter = 1.0 / (f_filter**(f_filter/f_n))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f_filter)
```

[image]

Uneven weight makes a artificial trend (your random numbers are all positive uniforms), causing non-stationary. covariance only works for stationary data. Take a look at the resulting weighted data.

[image]

Comment: Hi, sloppy from me, I wanted to use Pct change  rather that absolute to address stationarity, just noticed my error readiing your response and have edited.  Stats look more in line this time.  I'm experimenting with is alternative methods of EWMA's that work on a strict window method, but the results still look further way than i expected, but much better than my sloppy fist go.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Using pct instead of absolute return would remove the non-stationary if you use EWMA properly ON A ROLLING WINDOW.